# wordpress return post_meta values lowest first

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following query which loops through posts that have a meta_value of "1284"

```
global $wpdb;

$table =  $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
$theid = get_the_id();
$todayVisits = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE meta_value = '$theid' LIMIT 1 ");

foreach ( $todayVisits as $post ){

echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().get_post_meta( $post->post_id, '_wholesale_price', true );

}
```

In the foreach loop i am then getting the meta key "_wholesale_price"

How do i go about only showing the lowest "_wholesale_price"?

I am have tried using the php function "min" like this:

```
min(array(get_post_meta( $post->post_id, '_wholesale_price', true ).','));
```

But i am guessing thats not the correct way as it didnt work.

> EDIT:

i have tried the following, but this returns the max value:

```
$price = min(get_post_meta( $post->post_id, '_wholesale_price', false ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$prices = get_post_meta($post->post_id, '_wholesale_price'); // get all prices
rsort($prices); // sort in descending order

$min_price = $prices[0]; // lowest
```